# Retrieving result set metadata from database without knowing the SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I am working in PHP and HTML and have created a database. I am connected to the database. I wondered if there was a way I could retrieve data from the database by asking a user to input the whole SQL statement. I really am interested in how I can fetch the data without saying something like  $row[‘id’]

For the sake of the argument they will know the columns and ids and everything about the database.

Everything I have seen is that you have to know what columns are being queried before you can access the data.

Comment: With the [MySQL SHOW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show.html) statement you can query what the DATABASES, TABLES and COLUMNS are. That should give you the information to build valid queries.

Answer (score 1):

If the your users are to supply the SQL statement to use, they must know the names of the tables and columns they want.

You can query the `information_schema.COLUMNS` table to find the names and data types of of tables and columns.

Or, once you have executed the query you can get the column metadata. With PDO use [$stmt->getColumMeta($columnNumber)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php);. With mysqli use [->result_metadata()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php) something like this (NOT debugged).

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT what,ever,else FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
$column_count = $mysqli->field_count();
$column_names = [];
for ($colnum = 0; $colnum < $column_count; $colnum++) {
    $field = $metadata->fetch_field();
    $column_names [] = $field->name;
}
$metadata->close();
```

This uses [->fetch_field()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) to get a whole mess of useful information about each column in your result set.

But letting users feed you SQL statements is a big security risk. If you trust your users to feed you SQL statements you must also trust them not to wreck or corrupt your data. If your system is open to the global internet you *will* lose your data. Ask me how I know this sometime.

[image]

Comment: Lol. That’s funny. I had to edit my post because I did not provide enough detail.

Comment: Oh, I understand now what you want. Please see my edit.